# Open HTML file from directory into webview Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I have an application where the user selects a html file from Download directory, this html in its head tag has `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

When I run my app in my pc browser all is good, but when I try to open in my webview android, the html file appears but not the css style.

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidProtocolHandler";
    private static final int RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE = 2;


    public Button buttonVerCurso;
    WebView webView;
    TextView textInfo;
    public String urlCurso;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textInfo = findViewById(R.id.info);
        buttonVerCurso = findViewById(R.id.abrirCurso);
        buttonVerCurso.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        textInfo.setText("");
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE){

            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

            if(clipData == null){
                urlCurso = data.getData().toString();
            }else{
                urlCurso = "clipData != null\n";
                for(int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    urlCurso = uri.toString();
                }
            }

        }
        webView.loadUrl(urlCurso);
        textInfo.append(urlCurso);
        Log.i(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>: " + urlCurso);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.abrirCurso:
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("*/*");
                String[] extraMimeTypes = {"text/*"};
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, extraMimeTypes);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Seleccione el archivo html de su curso",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default: return;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I show the html with its style?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is that file style.css?

Comment: `When I run my app in my pc browser` How does one run an Android app in a PC browser?

Comment: Wen I say that is because, in my pc I open the html in the browser only to see if the css is good (that files are into a folder called "test"), and that folder is into Dowloads directory on the phone

Answer (score 0):

**Put the file in your /assets also put css with in the directory and relocate css in html file and use:**

```
public class WebViewDemoActivity extends Activity {  

    private WebView mWebView;  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.web_view_layout);  

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_id);  
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: My files html and css is in a folder called "test" and that folder is into Dowloads directory on the phone

Comment: No You can loaded a website hard coded in your app. but for that you need to put them in your android project in folder name "android_asset"

Comment: theres is an app called "html reader" and that app can open my files html and the css

Answer (score 0):

You let the webview load your html file from a content scheme.

The css file is indicated as relative path.

But the browser cannot make a full path of it as it cannot decode the used folder from the content scheme.

Even if it could it would not have the right read permission.

Apparently your html source does not contain img tags otherwise you would have asked why the pictures were not loaded.

Comment: theres is an app called "html reader" and that app can open my files html and the css

Comment: Ok. But are you using the same uri to start that app? Or does the user choose the html file with that app itself?

Comment: the user choose the index html

Comment: With that app itself?

Comment: yes, this is the action:
1._ The user open the app and click a button
2._ Goes to Downloads directory and click html file

Comment: You understand now that then a classic file path like /storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.html is used? And if there is a src="mypicture.jpg" the browser can construct path /storage/emulated/0/Download/mypicture.jpg with which it can load the image? If yes then reread answer.

Comment: That app will use its own file picker. Correct?